# simple Userscript in Greasemonkey no longer working after functions added

Tags: jquery, screen-scraping, greasemonkey

I've just started to use Greasemonkey and am trying to make a userscript that will scrape a page -

Before I got into that I tried running a few tests to increase my familiarity with Greasemonkey (for example I tried an userscript that had just an alert, which worked). However, after I added functions, the alert (which is called at the top), failed to work- why is this happening?

```
//==UserScript==
'//@name stanfordWhoScraper
//@require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
//==/UserScript==
alert("TEST");
/*Functions*/
function jquerify(jquerified){
if(!(window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.jquery == '1.6.2')) {
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
jquerified = true;
return jquerified; 
}
}
function findName(url){
    if (!typeof url) return "Enter string url"
    var name = $("#PublicProfile h2").load(url);
    if (name == "") return "No name found";
    return name;
}'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with that script.  The 2 that keep it from running are:

1. Stray apostrophes as Artyom said.
   Change: `'//@name stanfordWhoScraper` to `// @name stanfordWhoScraper`  and
   change: `}'` to `}`.
2. Malformed [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block):
   Whitespace is **required** after the leading slashes.  This is wrong and fails:

   ```
   //==UserScript==
   //@name stanfordWhoScraper
   //@require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
   //==/UserScript==
   ```

   ***This* is correct:**

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name stanfordWhoScraper
   // @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
   // ==/UserScript==
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote on line 2. It starts a string that ends when another single quote is encountered (inside your function), and therefore no parsing is made.

Comment: I don't actually have that in the code- that's from stack overflow's enter code here thing

Comment: no, there aren't any- I even took out all of the functions and just had an alert displaying name, where name is   var name = $("#PublicProfile h2").load(url); and url is specified by me- it still doesn't work

Comment: @praks5432, Stackoverflow's code control does not put such artifacts into questions.   Paste the **exact** unedited code into the question.